# Linking category posts (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a category in Wordpress called News and would like to link to the next news page when viewing a story.

This is the existing code but will link to all posts, what should I add to make it just posts in the News category?

```
<div id="page-navi">
<div class="button previous"><?php previous_post_link('%link') ?></div>
<div class="button next"><?php next_post_link('%link') ?></div>
   </div><!-- page-navi -->
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [WordPress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link):

```
previous_post_link($format, $link, $in_same_cat = false, $excluded_categories = '')
```

So just add `true` as a third parameter:

```
<div id="page-navi">
<div class="button previous"><? previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous in category', true) ?></div>
<div class="button next"><?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next in category', true) ?></div>
   </div><!-- page-navi -->
```